# Count specifc table rows from multiple tables query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I need to count only the users table results from this exemple query:

```
SELECT 
count (1) filter (where coalesce(   users.membership_1_end > current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT',
                                    users.membership_2_end > current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT',
                                    users.membership_3_end > current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT',
                                    users.membership_4_end > current_timestamp at time zone 'GMT')) as active_subs 
from users,invoices
```

Happens that this counting is ok when only the table users is in the query, and returns a crazy value when invoices is added to the query.

How can I filter only the users table results in the counting?

Comment: Please show us some sample data and expected output

Comment: You are not joining the two tables and thus you are creating a cross join between them. Something that wouldn't happen if you use an explicit JOIN operator instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins